# Raven db order by issue

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, ravendb

I have collection of documents:

```
{
"Name": "MyName",
"LabelKey": "MyLabelKey"
}
```

In collection LabelKey could be null or could not be in document. If I try to order this list using linq:

```
session.Query<MyMetaData>().OrderBy(x => x.LabelKey).ToList()
```

I'm getting only records which have LabelKey not null. So if I have collection of 100 documents and only 2 have LabelKey values, after I ordering I'll get only 2. I need to order all collection even if they have LabelKey null. If I try to check not null I get exception:

```
Could not understand how to translate '(x.LabelKey != null)' to a RavenDB query.
Are you trying to do computation during the query?
RavenDB doesn't allow computation during the query, computation is only allowed during index. Consider moving the operation to an index.
```

Any ideas how can I order all collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Don't store nulls.  On the way in, check for null and replace with an empty string.

**Approach 2**

Create a static index.  In the `Map` expression, use the null coalescing operator, such as:

```
LabelKey = x.LabelKey ?? string.Empty
```

Then query using that index.

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that for sorting RavenDb will use the value "empty". At least that's what I'm experiencing. If you leave it at null it uses "null".